# jetty-maven-plugin - run maven goal before restarting jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am using **`jetty-maven-plugin`**. Exacly `jetty:run` goal which starts jetty servlet container. This maven plugin can as well scan some directories and automaticly restarts when discovers changes in these directories. I can configure this plugin to scan my source files for changes, but I can not force it to recompile them before restart :(

**I am wondering if there is any way to run maven goals like `compile` before restarting jetty?**

At the moment when I change for example java file I must manually run `mvn:compile`.